# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have this piece of code in a PL/SQL procedure, where I want to declare a variable `MAX_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` with a default value, and after that assign a value from the DB, but I got an error

```
create or replace PROCEDURE check_in_time 

IS

    MAX_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS number := 4480;    

    SELECT TO_NUMBER (PARAMETER_VALUE) INTO MAX_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS
    FROM SYSTEM_PARAMETER 
    WHERE PARAMETER_NAME = 'CHECK_IN_MAX_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS';

   CURSOR chekin_time_cursor

    IS

      SELECT username....WHERE  seconds_in_wait >= MAX_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS

 BEGIN

..
```

Comment: I modified the example based on your newly added code; have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you missed the BEGIN keyword:

[EDIT] After you modified your code, I did the same with mine: you should keep all declarations in its own section. Then, after the BEGIN keyword, perform SELECT into that variable you've previously declared.

[EDIT #2] If you want to pass a parameter to a cursor, here's how to do that. I included some more code (opening and fetching from cursor, etc.).

```
create or replace procedure check_in_time 
is
  max_timeout_in_seconds number := 4480;

  cursor chekin_time_cursor (par_timeout number) is
    select username from ... where seconds_in_wait >= par_timeout;
  c1r chekin_time_cursor%rowtype;
begin
  select to_number(parameter_value)
    into max_timeout_in_seconds
    from system_parameter
    where parameter_name = 'CHECK_IN_MAX_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS';

  open chekin_time_cursor(max_timeout_in_seconds);
  loop
    fetch chekin_time_cursor into c1r;
    exit when chekin_time_cursor%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(c1r.username);
  end loop;

  close chekin_time_cursor;
end;
/
```

Comment: ok, but 4480 is the default value, I would like to have the value I got from the query after the Begin, so the cursor will never have that value because is declared before I got that value

Comment: I included some more code into the example; have a look.